# Using racket to recursively sum nested lists within a list of permutations

Tags: racket

I have a list of numbers and a list of operators in racket.

```
(define numList (list 5 25))
(define ops '(+ *))
```

I am using the **cartesian-product** to join the operators to each possible permutation of the list of numbers.

```
(cartesian-product ops (permutations numList))
```

which gives the following result;

```
'((+ (5 25))
  (+ (25 5))
  (* (5 25))
  (* (25 5)))
```

I want to sum each nested list, ie (+ (5 25)) and then add them to a list.
I have managed to do the following so far using the **eval** keyword;

```
(define ns (make-base-namespace))

(list (eval
   (flatten
    (cadr
     (cartesian-product ops (permutations numList))))ns ))
```

Which removes the nesting of each list and performs the sum on the first 3 elements and returns a value of 50 (+ (5 25)). 
I want to perform this recursively on each nested section before the flatten is performed. I know that I'll be able to use **remove-duplicates** too.
 I'm new to Racket, but here's what i have so far;

```
(define (evalCart l)
(if (null? l)
  0
  (list
   (eval
    (flatten
     (cadr
      (cartesian-product ops (permutations numList)))) ns ) (evalCart (car 
l)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval` is a bit overkill. You can instead determine which procedure you want by comparing for symbol equality. Since racket has first class procedures, you can just return the procedure itself. For instance:

```
(define (get-procedure term)
  (case term
    [(+) +]
    [(-) -]
    [(*) *]
    [(/) /]))
```

If you don't know `case` you can use a `cond` form

```
(cond [(eq? term '+) +] ...
```

Then you can use this with `apply` as in

```
(define (evaluate term)
  (define procedure (get-procedure (first term)))
  (define arguments (second term))
  (apply procedure arguments))
```

Then you can `map` the procedure `evaluate` as in

```
(map evaluate (cartesian-product ops (permutations numList)))
```

This will give you a list of numbers. In the case of the list of four elements you gave, you would get `'(30 30 125 125)`, which I believe is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a million for your time and effort, that's perfect. Unfortunately i don't have enough reputation to vote you up, but let's just say it's a +1 !